# Adding custom css to image side of Text & Image block in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Following the guide at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fJSUs0bTPMc I can add a "red-text" class to the text side of the block and, using the Customize --> Additional CSS page watch the changes applied live.

This does not work, however, for the image.  I just want to apply rounded corners, which should be as simple as .my-rounded-image { border-radius: 30px; }, but it is not.

More specifically:

1. Add "red-text" to Advanced --> Additional CSS Classes for one of the paragraph blocks on the text side.
2. Add "my-rounded-image" to Advanced --> Additional CSS Classes for the image side
3. Publish page, View page, Customize Page
4. Go to Additional CSS in Customize view
5. Add .red-text { color:red; } and see it updated on the paragraph previously modified
6. ???? Cannot get anything applied to image

I have tried this with a normal image block without success as well.

Comment: You might need to `!important` property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `overflow: hidden;` as well:

```css
.wp-block-media-text__media {
  border-radius: 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```